# Windows 10 pc can’t shutdown via software anymore. How do i fix it?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

This happens about 50% of the times i start the computer up. I can’t find anything about this anywhere online

Here’s a video showing the problem: https://youtu.be/uBFxEi-_x7A

The button on the start menu does nothing and even the cmd command shutdown /s or shutdown /s /t 0 just hangs (even when admin and no other processes are running)

Even when i press the hardware button it gets stuck at the loading screen that says “afsluiten” (shutdown in dutch)

The only way i can get it to shutdown is to hold the hardware button for a force shutdown

Comment: Is fastboot enabled ? (It is default on in Windows 10). If so, disable it first and see if that helps. Some device drivers don't play nice with fastboot which can cause this sort of trouble.

Comment: I tried searching how to disable fastboot and from what i understand there is supposed to be a third option here: https://imgur.com/a/14CoHoh to turn off fast boot. But i dont see it. Or am i looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: That is the wrong screen. Those are the power-management settings. I don't have a W10 system at hand. But if memory serves: Find the "Choose what the power buttons do" settings page. There should be a "shutdown settings" under which you can uncheck "Turn on Fast Startup". The wording is probably a bit different in the Dutch Windows version but I never use Windows in Dutch so I wouldn't know. (Even though I'm Dutch myself I started computing in the 70's when it was all English and I never got used to translated user-interfaces. )

Comment: Look at the screenshot it says “instellingen voor afsluiten” which i think is the dutch version of shutdown settings right? But i don’t have a third option other then the sleep mode and hibernate mode check boxes. The only reason i use the dutch version is because it is what the computer came with. But i am realy considering a fresh install cause i have also been having issues with disk management.

Comment: You're right. That is the right spot. If you don't see the option there your computer doesn't have Fast Startup available, which is not unusual depending on which CPU and motherboard chipset the computer has internally. So it is off anyway in your case.

Comment: I am not sure whether my Answer will help or you have some other issue , but it is worth a quick try. I have updated my Answer with a "Possible Work-Around" to not seeing the "wanted" setting , which is to execute `powercfg /hibernate on` ; Do try & check whether that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In Control Panel, go to "Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings" :

Navigation : **Control Panel : System & Security : Hardware & Sound : Power Options : Choose what the Power Buttons Do** : You should get this :

[image: POWER]

In case you see only some setting & not the wanted "fast start" setting, then you may have to execute this command:
`powercfg /hibernate on`

With that, when you reopen the Control Panel, you should hopefully see 4 settings.

**You may have to click the highlighted text to get this:**

[image: POWER]

**Disable that here !**
You can now check if your Issue Persists or ShutDown goes more smoothly !

Comment: I do see the setting now and it has always been off, but i installed some windows updates. It gave me a bluescreen but after that the shutdown button seems to be working

Comment: Oh ok. It could be the "Powercfg" turned it off. In case , you want to confirm that this setting was not the actual reason , you could turn it on , & try it for a few Days. If Power Off ( ShutDown ) is still going smooth with "fast start" on , then that is not the culprit. If Issue comes back , then that is the culprit. This is only if you want to confirm whether this setting is the culprit.

Comment: Nope it is back with the setting off so they are most likely not connected. The only thing i can connect to the issue is that i am trying to flash a sd card at some point the program hangs and after that my shutdown button seems to stop working. I am going to do some more testing (i am using raspberry pi imager)

Comment: It is most likely that the SD Card Device Driver is hanging & is not giving a "green Signal" to Shut Down , which is preventing the OS from terminating it & then Shutting Down. You might want to Disable that Device & check. Also try to update that Driver.

Comment: I will try that. I eventually ended up just using a usb drive.